# Nested loop iteration

Tags: javascript

I'm using a nested loop to iterate over an array `bookingArray`. If the `bookingArray` item `roomNumber` matches the index of the first loop `i`, that `bookingArray` item should be pushed to a new array `tableArray`.

I'm running into an issue whereby multiple entries from my `else` statement are added to the resultant `tableArray`. It could potential be related to correct usage of `break` / `continue`? I've read up on the documentation but the correct solution eludes me.

**Expected Result:**

```
"1: room booked",
"2: room available",
"3: room available",
"4: room available",
"5: room booked",
"6: room available",
"7: room available",
"8: room available",
"9: room booked",
"10: room available"
```

**Fiddle of current code:**

```js
var bookingArray = [{
    "roomNumber": 1,
  },
  {
    "roomNumber": 5,
  },
  {
    "roomNumber": 9,
  }
];

var tableArray = [];


for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < bookingArray.length; j++) {
    if (i == bookingArray[j].roomNumber) {
      tableArray.push(bookingArray[j].roomNumber + ": room booked");
      break;
    } else {
      tableArray.push(i + ": room available");
    }
  }
}

console.log(tableArray);
```

Comment: what would you like tableArray to look like after the loop is complete?

Comment: I'm just testing the concept, the data is a lot different in the actual application. I'm happy with it just being an item in an array for the purpose of this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the inner loop runs multiple times for every outer loop iteration. Use the inner loop just to set a flag and once it completes then push once per  outer loop iteration based on that flag:

```js
var bookingArray = [{
    "roomNumber": 1,
  },
  {
    "roomNumber": 5,
  },
  {
    "roomNumber": 9,
  }
];

var tableArray = [];


for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  var isBooked = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < bookingArray.length; j++) {
    if (i == bookingArray[j].roomNumber) {
      isBooked = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  var msg = isBooked ? ": room booked" : ": room available";
  tableArray.push(i + msg);
}

console.log(tableArray);
```

Comment: Thank you chariletfl eloquent solution

Answer (score 1):

charlietfl's solution is correct. As an alternative, using the library lodash can shorten this code considerably. It can be done in two lines, as shown below

```js
var bookingArray = [{
    "roomNumber": 2,
  },
  {
    "roomNumber": 5,
  },
  {
    "roomNumber": 9,
  }
];

var booked = _.map(bookingArray, 'roomNumber');
var unbooked = _.difference(_.range(11), booked);

console.log("Booked:", booked);
console.log("Not Booked:", unbooked);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Adding an external library does have a bit of overhead to download, but if you find other spots in your app where lodash is useful (I usually do), then it may be worthwhile to include.

I have no affiliation with the lodash team.